# iTextSharp -- When creating a new PDF from scratch -- how do I add form fields?

Tags: asp.net, itext

I am using iTextSharp, and have a new document being created in memory (I am combining multiple PDFs, then adding a new page with a digital signature on it.)

I have a bit of a problem however. I have my Document object, and everything outputs, but how the heck do I add a PdfFormField to a Document? Do I have to use the stamper? This exists only in memory and is not saved anywhere.

e.g:

```
Document document = new Document();
MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();

try
{
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

    document.Open();
    PdfContentByte content = writer.DirectContent;

    // .... content adds a bunch of pages in
}
finally
{
    document.Close();
}

return File(output.GetBuffer(), "application/pdf",
            "MRF-" + receipt.OrderNumber + ".pdf");
```

I have a signature block as such that I want to add to the end of the document:

```
 PdfFormField sig = PdfFormField.CreateSignature(writer);
 sig.SetWidget(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(100, 100, 250, 150), null);
 sig.Flags = PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT;
 sig.Put(PdfName.DA, new PdfString("/Helv 0 Tf 0 g"));
 sig.FieldName = "Signature1";
```

But I can't figure out for the life of me how to do something like `document.add(sig)` as it needs an `IElement`.

Comment: **Do not** call `GetBuffer()` on the `MemoryStream`, call `ToArray()` instead. The former includes uninitialized bytes which can/will produce a corrupt PDF.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed this discrepancy when every example in the world used ToArray (my bad!). Good to point out lest my bad examples ruin someone else :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's is the C#/ASP.NET version converted from Java, using [an example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=221) from the [iText book](http://itextpdf.com/book/) written by [the creator of iText](http://www.lowagie.com/):

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader(
  "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=signatureTest.pdf"
);        
using (Document document = new Document()) {
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
  document.Open();
  document.Add(new Paragraph("A paragraph"));
  PdfFormField sig = PdfFormField.CreateSignature(writer);
  sig.SetWidget(new Rectangle(100, 100, 250, 150), null);
  sig.FieldName = "testSignature";
  sig.Flags = PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT;
  sig.SetPage();
  sig.MKBorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK;
  sig.MKBackgroundColor = BaseColor.WHITE;
  PdfAppearance appearance = PdfAppearance.CreateAppearance(writer, 72, 48);
  appearance.Rectangle(0.5f, 0.5f, 71.5f, 47.5f);
  appearance.Stroke();
  sig.SetAppearance(
    PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, appearance
  );
  writer.AddAnnotation(sig);
}
```

If you take a look at the Java example you'll notice there is also code to **sign** the document, which is purposely left out of the example above. Signing PDF in ASP.NET is **not** a trivial task.